# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int' using Tensorflow v 1.12

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
def _parse_function(_file1, _file2):
        # live

        _file1 = _file1.decode('UTF-8')
        meta = glob.glob(_file1+'/*.png')
        try:
            fr = meta[random.randint(0, len(meta) - 1)]
        except:
            print(_file1, len(meta))
        im_name = fr
        lm_name = fr[:-3] + 'npy'
        #lm_name = fr[:-12] + '.npy'
        if os.path.isfile(lm_name):
            image = Image.open(im_name)
            width, height = image.size
            image_li = image.resize((imsize,imsize))
            image_li = np.array(image_li,np.float32)
            

            lm_li = np.load(lm_name, allow_pickle=True) / width
            lm_li = lm_li[0,:,:]
            
            print('_____________lm_li___________', lm_li.shape)
            if np.random.rand() > 0.5:
                image_li = cv2.flip(image_li, 1)
                lm_li[:,0] = 1 - lm_li[:,0]
                # print('________dimenstions of lmli_______', lm_li[lm_reverse_list,:].shape)
                lm_li = lm_li[lm_reverse_list,:]
                print('_____________lm_name_________', lm_name)
```

I am getting **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'** for the line `lm_li = np.load(lm_name, allow_pickle=True) / width`. Can someone explain how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It means that you are trying to divide a `NoneType` by an `int` (width). This is happening because `np.load(lm_name, allow_pickle=True)` is not working as you wish and is returning `None` instead of a number.

I suggest you double check your `np.load()` and see if you can load it by itself outside the function.